# Is it possible to push 2 separate instances of a UIViewController on a UINavigationContoller stack

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a generic UIViewController which has multiple uses. It can be instantiated for 6 different ways as it is designed to be very generic. Let us call this multipurpose viewcontroller as MultiPurposeViewController.

```
Type1VC = MultiPurposeViewController()// initiated differently
self.navigationController.push(Type1VC)
```

Inside Type1VC:

```
Type2VC = MultiPurposeViewController()// initiated differently than before
self.navigationController.push(Type2VC)
```

Is it allowed to do an operation with a navigation controller?

Edit:

- Will such an operation cause any memory issues?
- Is such an operation allowed when dealing with `UINavigationController` stack?
- Has anybody encountered such a scenario of stacking multiple instances of the same `UIViewContoller` onto a `UINavigationController` stack without having any memory leaks?

Comment: yes why not , but it is not good practice

Comment: What are the implications? Isn't every instantiation calling a separate memory location? Sorry for the questions but I'm curious to know why it wouldn't be good practice. Thank you for responding.

Comment: Yes, you can push separate instances without incident. Re whether your `MultiPurposeViewController` is a good design or not, (a) it could be, quite possibly, an excellent approach, depending upon the problem you were solving and how you implemented it; (b) it's not relevant to this question here; (c) we don't have enough information here to decide; and (d) this probably isn't even the right forum for that question (e.g. http://codereview.stackexchange.com is good venue for code reviews of functioning code).

Comment: What's the point of this question? Did you try doing what you asked? Did it work? What issue are you dealing with here?

Comment: @rmaddy this question was to try and see if anybody has encountered such a situation of stacking different instances of the same `UIViewController` onto a `UINavigationController` stack without having any memory issues. Thank you for responding as always.

Comment: But that's not what your question asked. You simply asked if it can be done. Clearly it can be. You need to update your question with something more specific.

Comment: @rmaddy the question has been updated. Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Official Apple Doc it is clearly mention :

> To implement a navigation interface, you must decide what data to
>   present at each level of your data hierarchy. For each level, you must
>   provide a content view controller to manage and present the data at
>   that level. If the presentation at multiple levels is the same, you
>   can create multiple instances of the same view controller class and
>   configure each one to manage its own set of data. For example, the
>   Photos app has three distinct presentation types.

You can read more by following : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html

Hope this will give you complete idea about your issue.
Feel free to comment.

Comment: Great! So if `MultiPurposeViewController` is designed correctly it can be reused at multiple levels without any memory issues! Thank you.

Comment: Yes , Make it correct answer if it solved your issue so  that other developer get benefit from your question . Keep coding